# are we able to Include(x=>x.Entity) then Select(x=> new Entity{ A=x.A })

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to call my `CompanyCatalog` table with its `FileRepo` table. There is a One to One relationship between them and i wanna apply when i `Include(x=>x.FileRepo.Select(a=> new{ FileName=a.FileNAme} ))` or any query like that.

Let me show to you my query in the bellow :

```
return TradeTurkDBContext.CompanyCatalog.Include(x=>x.FileRepo
.Select(x=> new FileRepo(FileName=x.FileName))).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

I'm trying to do something like that. I'm asking is it possible or not ? if it's possible then how ?

Comment: You want to get a `List<>` of your `CompanyCatalog` and you want bring related `FileRepo`? Why don't you just use `.Include(x => c.FileRepo)` only? I mean, it should work.

Comment: There is a property which called FileData and it has binary data. i dont wanna call that property because its making the query much slower. it keeps the files as binary Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a table of `CompanyCatalogs` and a table of `FileRepos`. Every `CompanyCatalog` has exactly one `FileRepo` (one-to-one), namely the one that the foreign key refers to.

If you've followed the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), you will have classes similar to the following:

```
class CompanyCatalog
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every CompanyCatalog has one FileRepo, the one that the foreign key refers to
    public int FileRepoId {get; set;}
    public virtual FileRepo FileRepo {get; set;}
}

class FileRepo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

    // every FileRepo is the FileRepo of exactly one CompanyCatalog
    // namely the one that the foreign key refers to
    public int CompanyCatalogId {get; set;}
    public virtual CompanyCatalog CompanyCatalog {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough for entity framework to detect your tables, the columns in the tables and the relations between the tables. If you had a one-to-many, you would have had a `virtual ICollectioni<...>` on the "one side". Only if you deviate from the conventions, for instance because you want other table names, or other column names, you need attributes or fluent API.

> In entity framework the columns are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, etc)

Foreign keys are columns in a table, hence they are not virtual. FileRepo is no column in the CompanyCatalogs table, hence it is declared virtual.

You want several properties of CompanyCatalogs, each with several properties of their FileRepos. You use `Include` for this. This is not necessary. A simple Select will do.

```
var companyCatalogs = dbContext.CompanyCatalogs
    .Where(catalog => ...)      // only if you don't want all CompanyCatalogs
    .Select(companyCatalog => new
    {
        // Select only the CompanyCatalog properties that you plan to use:
        Id = companyCatalog.Id,
        Name = companyCatalog.Name,
        ...

        // Select the FileRepo of this CompanyCatalog as one sub object
        FileRepo = new
        {
            Date = companyCatalog.FileRepo.Date,
            Title = companyCatalog.FileRepo.Title,
            ...
        },

        // if you want you can select the FileRepo properties one by one:
        FileRepoDate = companyCatalog.FileRepo.Date,
        FileRepoTitle = companyCatalog.FileRepo.Title,
    });
```

Entity Framework knows your relations, and because you used the virtual properties of the class, it knows it has to perform a (Group-)Join.

Comment: i have been searching this like 3 days. thank you for your wonderful answer. Because of u, my query is working so well and i dont need to useless properties anymore. Thank u again and again and again ! im not gonna use ```Include``` everytime after that.

Comment: I should have added: only fetch irems without `Select`, and only fetch using `Include` if you plan to update the fetched objects in the database using SaveChanges. In my other answers I explain why this is less efficient if you don't plan to update the data. One of the reasons is that you fetch more properties then you'll use, the other is that the DbContext will keep a copy of the fetched objects to detect which properties need to be updated in SaveChanges

Comment: im only using that to display data. there is a no update action for me. is it efficient as much as i think or not ? There is a Catalog and FileRepo tables in my database. there is a one to one relationship between them. im using that to take FileRepo.FileName,FileRepo.FileID so i can show to the user the document name and documentID . if he wanna download that document, then he needs to click on it and wait for to load that document. I'm doing that because im calling like 10-20 document for each time. i dont wanna call those documents in the one query, so he can use as much he needs to.

Comment: You can view the SQL created by SaveChanges using property `DbContext.Database.Log`. Assign an `Action(string) to it, and this function will be called with the SQL text. So you write a method `public void LogSql(string txt)`, and you assign it: `dbContext.Database.Log = slqText => LogSql(sqlText)`. I'm not sure, maybe you can do this without the lambda. you'll have to fiddle with this, to find the best method